# Наследование класса от object

Tags: python, ооп

Есть ли какая-то причина для наследования класса от `object`?

Я только что нашел код, который делает это, и не могу найти вескую причину, почему.

```
class MyClass(object):
    # Код класса...
```

<sub>перевод вопроса [Python class inherits object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015417/14227417) от участника [@tjvr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359640/tjvr)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015417/14227417

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В Python 3, помимо совместимости между Python 2 и 3, *нет причин*. В Python 2 *много причин*.

#### История Python 2.x

В Python 2.x (начиная с версии 2.2) есть два стиля классов в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия `object` в качестве базового класса:

- классы **«классического» стиля** не имеют `object` в качестве базового класса

  ```
  >>> class ClassicSpam:      # Нет базовых классов
  ...     pass
  >>> ClassicSpam.__bases__
  ()
  ```
- классы **«нового» стиля**, прямо или косвенно (например, наследуют от встроенного типа) имеют `object` в качестве базового класса:

  ```
  >>> class NewSpam(object):           # напрямую наследуется от object
  ...    pass
  >>> NewSpam.__bases__
  (<type 'object'>,)
  >>> class IntSpam(int):              # косвенно наслудуется от object...
  ...    pass
  >>> IntSpam.__bases__
  (<type 'int'>,) 
  >>> IntSpam.__bases__[0].__bases__   # ... потому что int наследуется от object
  (<type 'object'>,)
  ```

Без сомнения, при написании класса вы всегда захотите использовать классы нового стиля. У этого есть множество преимуществ, перечислю некоторые из них:

- [Поддержка дескрипторов](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). В частности, с дескрипторами возможны следующие конструкции:

  1. [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod): Метод, который в качестве неявного аргумента получает класс вместо экземпляра.
  2. [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod): Метод, который не принимает неявный аргумент self в качестве первого аргумента.
  3. свойства с [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property): Создание функций для получения, установки, и удаления атрибутов.
  4. [__slots__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots): Экономит потребление памяти, а также ускоряет доступ к атрибутам. Конечно, это [накладывает ограничения](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots).
- Статический метод `__new__`: позволяет настраивать создание экземпляров класса.
- [Порядок разрешения методов (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/): в каком порядке будут производиться поиск базовых классов класса при попытке определить, какой метод вызывать.

Если вы не наследуетись от `object`, забудьте об этом. [Здесь](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) можно найти более исчерпывающее описание предыдущих пунктов списка, а также другие преимущества классов «нового» стиля.

Одним из недостатков классов нового стиля является то, что сам класс требует больше памяти. Однако, если вы не создаете много объектов класса, я сомневаюсь, что это будет проблемой.

#### История Python 3.x

В Python 3 все упрощено. Существуют только классы «нового» стиля (называемые просто классами), поэтому единственная разница при добавлении `object`, требуется чтобы бы вы вводили еще 8 символов.

Это:

```
class ClassicSpam:
    pass
```

полностью эквивалентно (кроме их имени :-) этому:

```
class NewSpam(object):
     pass
```

и этому:

```
class Spam():
    pass
```

У всех есть `object` в `__bases__`.

```
>>> [object in cls.__bases__ for cls in {Spam, NewSpam, ClassicSpam}]
[True, True, True]
```

## Итак, что нужно делать?

В Python 2: всегда явно наследовуйтесь от `object`.

В Python 3: наследуйтесь от `object`, если вы пишете код, который пытается быть агностиком Python, то есть он должен работать как в Python 2, так и в Python 3. В противном случае нет, это действительно не имеет значения, поскольку Python вставляет его вместе вас.

<sub>перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/14227417) от участника [@DimitrisFasarakisHilliard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4952130/dimitris-fasarakis-hilliard)</sub>